# Why do gaps appear when I set borderLeftWidth=1 in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I have the following react-native code which does exactly what I want because it prints a solid black rectangle:

```
      getTable() {
            const cell = {
            backgroundColor:'black',
            flex:1,
            height:50,

            };
            const table = {
            borderColor:'black',
            borderLeftWidth:0,
            borderRightWidth:0,
            borderTopWidth:0,
            borderBottomWidth:0,
            width:'100%'};
            return (
                    <View style={table}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                                    <View style={cell}></View>
                                    <View style={cell}></View>
                                    <View style={cell}></View>
                            </View>
                    </View>
            );
    }
```

However, when I change the `table.borderLeftWidth` to a value of `1`, I see a white vertical line 66% from the left of the black box as depicted in this image:

[image]

Why does adding a border left to the container cause a white line to the interior content?

This issue happens in all iOS devices and all iOS simulated devices.  It does not appear in Android.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What device(s) does this happen on?

Comment: @EvanDarwin it happens on all iOS devices in the simulator and physical devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that this issue only occurs on iOS devices I'd suspect it's an issue with the iOS implementation. The [react-native issue #2089](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2089) on GitHub seems to be similar to what you're encountering.

The issue lies in react-native's "implementation" of CSS on iOS devices (since it's not actually CSS) and that it's simply a rendering bug (probably with flexbox). I'd recommend that you post about your issue there and see if they can resolve it.